# create-react-app + php

Tags: php, javascript, frontend, reactjs

Как подключить react к серверу php ,сейчас при build(npm run build) и подключении к php index.html ,видна только html страница,а скрипт не запускается ,а запускается только если запустить локальный сервер(npm start),вот как сделать чтобы npm start подключался к серверу appache(xampp),а не создавал локальный сервер.
Или просто как залить свой react проект на сервер c php?

Comment: У меня та же проблема. На локальном сервере все работает. Но после npm run build, в папке build я не нахожу php файлов. И когда заливаю все на хостинг, мое подключен к базе не работает. Webpack не включает php в production?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*расскажу вам страшную тайну*

то что вы пытаетесь сделать не есть хорошо и так не делается.
когда проект на реакте готов то делается так

> `npm run build`
>     Builds the app for production to the build folder. It
>   correctly bundles React in production mode and optimizes the build for
>   the best performance.   The build is minified and the filenames
>   include the hashes. Your app is ready to be deployed!   See the
>   section about deployment for more information.

коротко - этой командой вы пересобираете проект разработки в готовый проект для релиза. проект будет лежать в папочке  `build`
ее и заливаете себе в проект.

Comment: собственно это не ответ. Как сделать так что бы create-react-app при разработке ссылался на file.php?? при билде файл копирует и оно работает, при npm start файл не видно? как при разработке использовать PHP файлы? или билдить каждый раз? пометить в **\my-app\public\controller\HomeController.php не дает эффекта, делать eject не охота